# How to position modal-message

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am tring to position my modal message and i am trying with following code.
But it's not working.

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of:    window  } });

var position = $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "option", "position" );
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "option", "position", { my: "20 200", at: "1 1", of: window  } );
```

Please find more about modal message here. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: Where do you want hte modal to be? Left top corner or left bottom corner ?

Comment: Please provide a jsbin so you can help us help you.

Comment: please setup a jsfiddel

Comment: I want 200px down from the top

Comment: You mean modAl message box, not modEl right?

Answer (score 0):

The `my` attribute is the position of the modal you want to pin.
The `at` attribute is where you want to place the `my` attribute.

`#dialog-message` will be at the left top corner. Becuase you place the left top of the modal box (`my`) at the left top corner of the window (`at`)

`#dialog-message2` will be at the right bottom corner. Becuase you place the right bottom of the modal box (`my`) at the right bottom corner of the window (`at`)

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left top", of:    window  } });
$( "#dialog-message2" ).dialog({ position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of:    window  } });
```

Or if you want to adjust in pixels you should choose `left+px` and `top+px`: (see http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left+20 top+200", of:    window  } });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k976vqs5/5/

You should switch the `my` and `at` values.

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "option", "position", { my: "left top", at: "left+20 top+200", of: window  } );
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesnot work when i change the position value.

Comment: Can you show it on a jsfiddle what the problem is? Because on mine you can see that the modal is at 200px of the top. Or does it need to be centered ?

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee I changed my answer. It should be `left+20` and `top+200` instead of `20` and `200`